# iOS: Unexpected repeated request in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've been using `AFNetworking` for sync information and found that it sends more than one request to the server when I apply `multithreading` but I only execute one request statement.

This problem can be traced using a sniffer application, because `Xcode debugger` can't make a trace of the request.

Also , I noticed this happen when the internet connection slows down.

Here is some code that I execute

Start sync

```
- (void)SyncFull
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(FinishSyncFull:)
                                                 name:@"FinishSyncFull" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(RemoveNotificacions:) name:@"RemoveNotificacions" object:nil];

    [[PivotService getInstance] sync];


}
```

Notification to continue synchronizing

```
-(void)FinishSyncFull:(NSNotification*) Notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"FinishSyncFull" object:nil];

    if ([SyncManager getInstance] mustSync])
    {

        [[FMDBHelper getInstance] RemoveDataFromTable:@"SyncInfo"];
        [[FMDBHelper getInstance] RemoveDataFromTable:@"SyncDetails"];


        [self startSyncFull];
     }
}
```

Description of `startSyncFull` function:

```
- (void)startSyncFull
{

    [[ServiceEntity1 getInstance] sync];

    [[ServiceEntity2 getInstance] sync];

    [[ServiceEntity3 getInstance] sync];

(...)
    }
```

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to all the places where you have requests executed, to verify that you really aren't executing more than one?

Comment: I verified that they're not executing more than one debugging the code.

Answer (score -2):

You can only make http requests in the main thread so you have to execute every request in that threat using:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //Your request      
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I make a new request after receive a notification from the result of a request before. I'm not sure how the threads usage is going in this point,but it can be the reason of fail?. I'll test your advice.

Comment: Your recomendation isn't valid because synchrous call on main thread for request makes frezze the application